# Why is bash -c cutting off the end of my script?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a simple script, that is essentially a list of `dpkg -i ...` commands in a `chroot`.

It looks something like this:

```
chroot /path/to/chroot /bin/bash -e << EOF
cd /opt

dpkg -i package1_*

dpkg -i package50_*
dpkg -i package51_*

dpkg -i package100_*

EOF
```

The problem is, when I call the script like, `bash -c "script here"` or `bash <( echo "script here" )`, i get an error message.

The error message looks something like:

```
Selecting previously unselected package libss2:i386.
(Reading database ... 1376 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack libss2_1.42.9-3ubuntu1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libss2:i386 (1.42.9-3ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libss2:i386 (1.42.9-3ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.5) ...
/bin/bash: d: not found
```

It seems like the code is cut off at `d(pkg -i ...)`.

I changed the `dpkg` that is being cut off to an `echo`. The error message stayed the same, only that now `e` is not being found.

I could of course save the script in a temp file and call it, since that works. But I would like to know what is happening here. The cutoff mark (including the 'd') is at the 1048 byte point.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior. Is there a difference between `bash <( echo "script here")` and `bash <( cat scriptfile )`? (Where the file scriptfile contains your script.)

Comment: Probably one of those dpkg -i commands is reading from stdin (which is that here-script). Try `bash /dev/fd/3 3<< EOF...` or `bash -c "$(cat << EOF...)"` instead.

Comment: @michas That did work. Good alternative. but what if my script is the output of another command?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: There are. So the bytes they try to read in as an answer are the missing bytes at the end?